# Can't move between my activities

Tags: android, android-activity

The emulator collapses when I run the attached code. Can not move between my activities. What is the problem?

Java Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    findViewById(R.id.btnPass).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(settings.this, WaitressRecord.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

XML Code :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="עבור"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.982"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you defined  android:onClick="onClick" in settings.xml file.so you can use this method

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    }

        public void onClick (View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(settings.this, WaitressRecord.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: btw. I added a variable that pass form the first activity to the second one.
 I want the info that has accepted from the first activity pass to the new activity and will save on new double variable, and will display as permanent on a textView, and not only when I click the button

Comment: How do you want it?Without clicking the button....anyway for parse data between activity's you must use putExtra and getExtras

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
     Button   btnPass= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPass);
 }
  btnPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(settings.this,WaitressRecord.class);
        startActivity(intent);
         }
       });
```

**or you can do this using Onclick method**

```
public void YourMethodName(View view) {// your onclick method 
      Intent intent = new Intent(settings.this, WaitressRecord.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}


 <Button
android:id="@+id/btnPass"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="עבור"
android:onClick="YourMethodName" // mention your method name 
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.982"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />
```